# convert date and time from factor to numerics in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which contains date and time for the columns. Let's name this dataframe date_time. Since the data type is factor type, I would like to convert the whole column of date_time to numerics without changing anything, eg 2020-01-20 14:02:50 to 20200120140250.

I have about 1000 rows of data. Does anyone knows how to produce the output? I have tried as.numeric and gsub but they doesnt work. I think using POSIXct might work but I do not understand the reasoning behind it.

example of my data:

```
2020-07-08 21:40:26 
2020-07-08 16:48:57 
2020-07-01 15:54:10 
2020-07-13 20:27:06 
2020-07-27 16:08:12
```

and the list goes on.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
gsub("[[:punct:] ]", "", as.character(as.POSIXct("2020-01-20 14:02:50")))
```

The `as.character` keeps the visual output instead working with the underlying numbers.

**UDPATE**:

```
date_time <- data.frame(time = as.POSIXct(
  c("2020-07-08 21:40:26", "2020-07-08 16:48:57", "2020-07-01 15:54:10",
    "2020-07-13 20:27:06", "2020-07-27 16:08:12", "2020-01-20 14:02:50")))

date_time$num_time <- gsub("[[:punct:] ]", "", as.character(date_time$time))
```

Comment: hi thanks but i would like to change all the date and time in the whole columns into numerics, so where do i put the name of the data frame?

Comment: can you provide a sample of you data format?

Comment: i updated the code above, hope this helps

Comment: hi thanks it helps if i were to change only 1 date time, but i have about 1000 rows of date time, for example:
my dataframe is called date_time with the following data:

data_time (column name)
2020-07-08 21:40:26
2020-07-08 16:48:57
2020-07-01 15:54:10
2020-07-13 20:27:06

and the list goes on (until row 1000). 

How to do i change all of them into numerics form?

Comment: i have updated the example with your data.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with `lubricdate`

```
dt1 <- as.factor(c("2020-07-08 21:40:26", "2020-07-08 16:48:57", "2020-07-01 15:54:10",
                  "2020-07-13 20:27:06", "2020-07-27 16:08:1"))   
   
dt <- data.frame(date=ymd_hms(dt1)) 
dt
class(dt$date)
```

Result

```
               date
1 2020-07-08 21:40:26
2 2020-07-08 16:48:57
3 2020-07-01 15:54:10
4 2020-07-13 20:27:06
5 2020-07-27 16:08:01
> class(dt$date)   
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```